# keyerror: in dictionary python3

Tags: python-3.x

i'm receiving a key error for the below code. i'm reading a file called names.txt which has both name and age of a person. All names are in lower case but when i do name.lower() function while searching in the dictionary, it's throwing the key error.

```
fo = open('names.txt' ,'r')
data = fo.readlines()
fo.close()
dicti = {}
for i in data:
    new_list = i.split(',')
    dicti[new_list[0].lower()] = new_list[1].strip('\n')
name = input ('enter the name to be searched: ')
if name.lower() in dicti.keys():
    print (dicti[name])
elif name == 'exit':
    quit()
else:
    print ('name ' + name.title() + ' not found')
```

file names.txt data is:

```
 Sophia,35
 Emma,28
 Olivia,16
 Isabella,10
 Ava,9
 Mia,26
 Emily,4
 Abigail,33
```

Can someone please tell me about the error.

Comment: You used `name.lower()` only for checking if the key was in the dictionary.  You used `name` itself when actually retrieving the value from the dictionary, which is of course going to fail if it wasn't typed in all lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this:

```
if name.lower() in dicti.keys():
    print (dicti[name])
```

You check that the lower-cased name is in the dicti, but then access it as is, without lower-case conversion. The proper code would be:

```
if name.lower() in dicti.keys():
    print (dicti[name.lower()])
```